# How to set the position of QMainWindow?

Tags: qt, position, window, qt5

In my rather complex app, I create several QmainWindows, which show/hide depending on conditions. To make their behavior more deterministic, I want to set their position using `setPosition()`. The problem is that QMainWindow is not derived from QWindow, as I assumed. So, it has no `setPosition()`. My questions:

- Why QMainWindow is not derived from QWindow? (Just my curiosity)
- How can I set the position of a QMainWindow?

Comment: Why `move(int x, int y)` is not suitable for you?

Comment: QWindow is rather new class and is an adapter between native and platform independent UI windows. QWidget is historically the parent for most of Qt UI classes. In fact that QWindow is not for long there yet. And yes, QMainWindow is derived from QWidget.

Comment: @Tarod because I found setPosition() :). And also, because I attempt to set before I show() it. Thanks, I am uneducated in Qt history.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*(@Tarod and @AlexanderVX already gave the answers in the comment, but here they are again)*

> Why QMainWindow is not derived from QWindow?

Mainly because `QMainWindow` existed long before `QWindow` was invented.

`QMainWindow` inherits `QWidget`. `QWidget` is flexible; it can become a top-level window, or it can become part of a larger widget. This means you can put `QMainWindow` inside another widget (but you probably don't want to do that).

> How can I set the position of a QMainWindow?

The same way you set the position of any other `QWidget`: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#pos-prop (`QWidget::move()`)